# Most important tells

Tags: live

I would like to start to play poker at casino near my home. I usually play on line. I would like to know which are, in your opinion, the most important tells to take care at brick and mortar poker.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the chip glance as the flop, turn, or river come out. Indicates they hit the flp/t/r in some way and their initial intention is to bet.

A chatty player is almost always a good hand, especially on the river when your contemplating a call against a player.

Shaking hands when betting is usually a monster, not a bluff.

I'm far from an expert but I think most would agree these are ones seen often and are pretty reliable.

Comment: On the flip side, my experience has been that if a player is being really chatty facing a bet and they shove over the top, they rarely have it.

Comment: Another valuable one is the "is it my turn"? from a usually inattentive player...indicates strength.

Answer (score 1):

Giving off:

- Know your stack size before the hand starts and who you have covered.  Don't wait for a good hand to count.
- Use the same mechanics.  If you bet left handed then always bet left handed.
- Rest your hands in the same spot.
- Don't announce your bet some times.  Do it the same way every time.  Annie Duke caught a tell in player announced raise to the dealer when he was bluffing.  Another pro caught a tell of player used smaller denomination chips when it was a bluff.
- If you are going to check your cards on the flop then always check
  your cards. A flop came up three diamonds and a guy immediately checked his cards.  Sammy Farah at the end of the hand said you have queens and one red.  You checked to see if it was a diamond and he was right.
- Wait your turn pre to check your cards.  Be in a body position to play the hand. Don't sit up tall after you hit a monster.
- Take the same amount of time to make an action.  Don't rush a bluff
  to look strong.  If you insta call it means you probably have piece of it but did not smash the board.  You did not even consider a raise.
- If it is a fold then go ahead and fold. If you think they might be bluffing you but you don't even have a bluff catcher then take the standard time.
- Don't ask the player for count some times and some times ask the
  dealer.
- Don't talk.
- Don't try and give off fake tells!

Read

- Do they act different. Do they act more confident some times? Was that a bluff or a monster.  Notice the tell and know what it means are not the same.
- Starting out I think you should more remember the betting pattern
  then what they showed.

Comment: I like this one. Those small tips are pretty serious. I remember my last quite-evident tell: When having pocket rockets I tended to turn my eyes away every sight. Damn. It was a hard week to me.

Answer (score 0):

Single stand alone tell is really not enough to get any good advantage.

You need to observe, if the player you are focused on try to act and bluff you, or not. Many players just try to hide their emotions and do not act, while many others try to signal tells that are opposite to their hand strength.

[Caro's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580420826) of poker tells is really great source of information about this topic.